# Scala list find minimum difference of elements

Tags: scala

My scala list as below

```
List(12,14,16,18,20,22,28,30)
```

Now my expected output as find difference of list from reverse order like   `30-28=2,28-22=6,22-20=2....` in this way so my new list will be

```
List(2,6,2,2,2,2,2)
```

And from this list fetch most common value so in this case minimum difference is 2 so final output will be minimum difference which is 2.

Comment: `most common value so in this case minimum difference is 2 so final output will be minimum difference which is 2.` Which do you want? Most common value, or minimum? The two are in general not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to have a solution with `sliding` too. :)

```
List(12,14,16,18,20,22,28,30).sliding(2).map(l => l(1) - l(0)).min
```

Comment: Probably could use an absolute value in there.

Comment: @ChrisMartin After seeing senia's answer I was considering, but as the question was stated as "difference of list from reverse order" I thought this might be what was the question about. (Probably the input is always in ascending order? Which case taking `abs` would not make a difference.)

Answer (score 3):

You could `zip` your list with its tail to get pairs of elements with `l zip l.tail` or `(l, l.tail).zipped`.

```
val l = List(12,14,16,18,20,22,28,30)

(l, l.tail).zipped.map{ (a, b) => math.abs(a - b) }.min
// 2
```